# Why appears the ToolTip in the background

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tooltip

I search for a ToolTip for a tkinter app. Now I found on youtube an example. But this ToolTip appears at the background, what is not usefull. How can I bring it always in front of my app, so that the user realize it?

See my picture: The ToolTip text appears behind my App window.
How can I move it infront of my App?

[ToolTip, snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsAna.png)

by Jack Shutzman https://youtu.be/MC9nuMBd390

```
from tkinter import *
class CreateToolTip(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, text='widget info'):
        self.waittime = 500
        self.wraplength = 180
        self.widget = widget
        self.text = text
        self.widget.bind('<Enter>', self.enter)
        self.widget.bind('<Leave>', self.leave)
        self.widget.bind('<ButtonPress>', self.leave)
        self.id = None
        self.tw = None
        
    def enter(self, event = None):
        self.schedule()
        
    def leave(self, event = None):
        self.unschedule()
        self.hidetip()
        
    def schedule(self):
        """ Show the tip """
        self.unschedule()
        self.id = self.widget.after(self.waittime, self.showtip)
        
    def unschedule(self):
        id = self.id
        self.id = None
        if id:
            self.widget.after_cancel(id)
            
    def showtip(self, event=None):
        """ Create the window for the tip """
        x = y = 0
        x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
        # The shift from top/left of the widget, for the tip to show
        x += self.widget.winfo_rootx() + 25
        y += self.widget.winfo_rooty() + 20
        # creates a toplevel toplevel window (like Frame, used for pop upor dialogue)
        self.tw = Toplevel(self.widget)
        # Leaves only the label and removes the app window decorations (wm -window manager)
        self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
        # self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(False) # to see the windo decorations
        self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x,y))
        
        # For Mac OS
        try:
            self.tw.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle",
                            "style", self.tw._w,
                            "help", "noActivates")
        except TclError:
            pass
        label = Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',
                      background="white", relief='solid', borderwidth=1,
                      wraplength= self.wraplength)
        label.pack(ipadx=1)
        
    def hidetip(self):
        tw = self.tw
        self.tw= None
        if tw:
            tw.destroy()
```

I need mybe also post, how I use it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ToolTip

....

loadbtn = tk.Button(labelframe, text='Load', width=15, command=self.buttonLoadIni)
loadbtn.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
ToolTip.CreateToolTip(loadbtn, 'Load the Settings.ini file')
```

for your reference:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ToolTip

def load():
    pass

root = tk.Tk()
loadbtn = tk.Button(root, text='Load', width=15, command=load)
loadbtn.grid(row=1,column=0, padx=10, pady=5)
ToolTip.CreateToolTip(loadbtn, 'Load the Settings.ini file')

root.mainloop()
```

Bad positioning of ToolTip:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMZq1.png)

Good positioning (built in) - maybe this can be used ???:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EutPk.png)

Comment: The example that you have included does not reproduce the issue for me.

Comment: Please see my picture. The TopLevel window comes hidden. Maybe this gives you an idea, what my problem is. The ToolTip text " Setting.ini file" shows up behind my app window.

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. It still only needs a single button widget, but we shouldn't have to patch together two separate blocks of code and guess at what "...." means.

Comment: Ive tried the code you included again, still i cant get the issue your experiencing

Comment: @BryanOakley,   please find a smal test code and the pictures, what I mean. The visability of the ToolTip code is not realy good infront. Maybe I can use the standard tooltip from tkinter window, but I don't know how I can use that, see other picture.

Comment: @CoolCloud , I use python 3.8.2

Comment: Is your root window with the attribute '-topmost'?

Comment: @Hermann12 Tkinters does not have any inbuilt tooltip, perhaps do you want to try `Pmw`? Anyway take a look at [this Q and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63685035/13382000)

Comment: @Atlas435, whar does thin men? Can I set the Toplevel() window on topmost?

Comment: @Atlas435, .attributes("-topmost", True) does't work in this case for Toplevel. It shows than the Toplevel window with decoration.

Comment: @Hermann12 I am asking you if your root window already has the attribute topmost. If so, that's maybe the reason for this behaviour, because the topmost will above all other windows. Another possible solution ist to call `root.upadte_idletasks()` after creating your tooltip.

Comment: @Atlas435 His tooltip seems to have `self.tw = Toplevel(self.widget)` it on the widget, would that be the cause of problem here. Just `Toplevel()` might be fine i guess.