# Error "__init__() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" when I only have the 3 arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay, so I am trying to make a tooltip, and ever since I tried making the test tooltip, I get an error with the dropdown box I am trying to bind it to.
I have tried giving it strings other than the list.
I am very new to this stuff, so I have no clue on what is going on here.

```
#Here I import tKinter to allow myself to create a UI
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import *

#This code creates the window.
root = Tk()

#This is a list of options for your government's control over the economy of your nation
econcontrol = ["Laissez Faire", "Some Government Intervention", "State Capitalism", "Planned Economy"]
econlaw = StringVar()
econlaw.set(econcontrol[0])

#Drop down box
dropdown = OptionMenu(root, econlaw, econcontrol)
dropdown.pack()

#tooltip
tip = Balloon(root)

#bind tooltip to thing
tip.bind_widget(dropdown, balloonmsg="Hello?")


#This code makes the window stay up.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include debugging details. Here's a helpful [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: This is perhaps an example of why not to use `from x import *`.

Comment: The correct call would be `OptionMenu(root, econlaw, *econcontrol)`, though I don't see immediately where the given error message comes from. `OptionMenu` expects the container, a variable, the initial value, and any additional values, all as separate arguments. `*econcontrol` alone works here since the first element of `econcontrol` is also the initially selected value.

Comment: To be more specific the error message comes from the `tkinter.tix.OptionMenu`, not the `tkinter.OptionMenu`, you are overriding one import statement with another import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the code `from tkinter.tix import *`, you should replace it with:

```
from tkinter.tix import Balloon 
# Or
import tkinter.tix # then tkinter.tix.Balloon(root)
```

But this wont *entirely* solve all your issues, because ever since version 3.6, `tix` is unmaintained, so the ToolTip will give you an error when you try to initialize it. What you can do here is, either use `Pmw` tooltip or create your own tooltip.

You can see an example of `Pmw.Balloon` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63681477/13382000) and you can also see how to make your own tooltip right below it too.