# Module working independently but raises an error when imported

Tags: python, tkinter, import, module, tix

So I was working with tkinter.tix module in Python to make a Scrollable window. It works flawlessly when I run the module independently but when I import it, it raises an error. Even if I independently import the tkinter.tix module in the main program, it causes error with other module in the main program( Image module from PIL which works perfectly until I import the tkinter.tix module, after which it of course raises an error).
Has anyone encountered this error before?
Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Code:

**Main Program:**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import TCRMenuOptions, STUMenuOptions

assignment = tk.Button(   #This button calls the function to display assignments
        master=frame,
        text="Assignment",
        font=font.Font(size=20, family="Helvetica"),
        image = asimg,
        compound = "top",
        width=200,
        height = 210,
        activebackground="White",
        bg="#33FFC5",
        bd=2,
        fg="DarkSlateGray",
        command = lambda: STUMenuOptions.viewassign(cls)
    )
```

**STUMenuOptions Module:**

```
def viewassign(cls):
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.config(background="#303939")
    root1.state('zoomed')
    frame = Frame(root1, bg="#303939", width="1366", height="768").grid(row=0, column=0)
    swin = ScrolledWindow(frame, width="1366", height="768")
    swin.grid(row=0, column=0)
    root = swin.window
    root.config(background="#303939")
    cls_lbl = Label(root, text="Current Assignments", font=font.Font(size=50, weight="bold"),bg="#303939", fg="Cyan").grid(row = 0, column = 0)

# Plus some other non relevant code
```

So when the button is pressed in the main program, it calls the viewassign(cls) function from STUMenuOptions module which it does, but then a blank window appears (There should be atleast the label "Current Assignments" ; atleast for the code I am posting here)and it raises the error which I have posted in previous edit but I am posting the full one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/abc2/Python/ComputerScienceProject/Main.py", line 324, in <lambda>
    command = lambda: STUMenuOptions.viewassign(cls)
  File "C:\Users\abc2\Python\ComputerScienceProject\STUMenuOptions.py", line 466, in viewassign
    swin = ScrolledWindow(frame, width="1366", height="768")
  File "C:\Users\abc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\tix.py", line 1348, in __init__
    TixWidget.__init__(self, master, 'tixScrolledWindow', ['options'], cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\abc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\tix.py", line 315, in __init__
    self.tk.call(widgetName, self._w, *extra)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "tixScrolledWindow"
```

Comment: btw you have the same problem with your `cls_lbl` variable as the one I described in my answer. Split it in 2 lines.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66013997/13382000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did this:

```py
frame = Frame(root1, bg="#303939", width="1366", height="768").grid(row=0, column=0)
```

In there you create a `tk.Frame` and immediately call its `.grid` method and store the result from the `.grid` (which is always None) in the variable `frame`. Then when you pass it in to `ScrolledWindow(frame, ...)` it confuses tkinter.

What you actually wanted to do is this:

```py
frame = Frame(root1, bg="#303939", width="1366", height="768")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

This problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385003/getting-values-from-object-oriented-tkinter/66385069#66385069) one. Always split creating the widget and packing/placing/gridding the widget on separate lines.

Comment: @CoolCloud Well that might be the reason. I just saw that mistake and thought that it might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yea probably, couldn't find any recent question or tags with `Tix`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I don't use ttk or tix but tix is still part of tkinter

Comment: I went through the files of `tix` from `tkinter` seems like something is off there.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks a ton....That got me for a while. So, all it boils down to is that the frame that is sent to ScrolledWindow contains None value. Thanks again.